# WebdriverJS ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, javascript

I'm new to Selenium and I think I'm just not understanding what is happening in the code and browser. I can work around my issue by replacing the driver.wait code (posted below) with a `driver.sleep(1000)` but I have been reading that sleep statements aren't ideal.

Can somebody help me figure out why the code I have isn't working and what exactly is going on? I can provide a full stack trace if it is helpful.

Here is what the code looks like.

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver')
const chrome = require("selenium-webdriver/chrome");
const By = webdriver.By
const until = webdriver.until

var username = "XXX"
var password = "XXX"

function login(username, password) {    
    // This part works fine
    driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('Email')))
    driver.findElement(By.id('Email')).sendKeys(username)
    driver.findElement(By.id('next')).click()

    // Here is where the element not visible happens
    driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('Passwd')), 5000)
    // driver.sleep(1000) works but I'm not sure why?
    driver.findElement(By.id('Passwd')).sendKeys(password)

    // Login
    driver.findElement(By.id('signIn')).click()
}

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        .withCapabilities({'browserName': 'chrome'}).build()
driver.get('https://gmail.com')
login(username, password)
```

Comment: This looks to be very similar to this question with the latest answer (April 6, 2017) showing the best solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43263908/3817795

Answer (score 3):

You are right, Selenium allows you to avoid such woodoo waits, gives you full control. And you know the drill: "with great power comes great responsibility". So:

1) learn to use helper class `ExpectedConditions: EC.presence_of_element_located()` - will wait until element is visible and clickable

2) Once you located element, save reference and use it, so you don't have to locate in next line again.

Comment: Do you have a reference to the ExpectedConditions class?  I found the Until class http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.html.  Is that something different?

Comment: I was able to get the code working with `ExpectedConditions` in Python but not in Javascript :(

Answer (score -1):

My solution:

- You are saying is correct. **In best practices we should avoid using explicit wait** `driver.sleep(5000)`
- Try to **use implicit wait** which will not wait unnecessarily. See below method:

  ```
   public void waitForElement(WebElement value)
   {
       // wait for field
       WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 90);

       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(value));
       System.out.print("."); // Just to verify code is used and working   
   }
  ```
- **Actual Use**:

  ```
  waitForElement(obj.your_web_element);
  ```

Comment: I'm using Javascript, not Java.